# Can't deploy SSIS package - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: sql-server, ssis, active-directory

I have an Azure Windows Server in a managed Domain (AD Domain Services) running SQL Server Enterprise.

I am trying to simply deploy a local (laptop) SSIS project to the remote SSIS server. When the deployment dialog appears and I enter the IP address of the VM, I get the dreaded:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. **(provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)** (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2146893019)

Importantly/Potentially related, I am using "Active Directory Password Authentication" and passing the credentials of a domain user (on the remote AD domain) which is an admin on the VM.

I tried also using SQL Authentication, but you cannot deploy a package using SQL Authentication (SSIS requirements).

I have searched long a wide for a solution to this, and a lot of hints point to changing a connection string, which doesn't apply to me since I'm using the VS2017 SSDT deployment wizard (no advanced options either).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open Windows CMD.EXE and type and enter the following and restart your computer:

```
netsh winsock reset
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681762/how-do-i-fix-an-error-connecting-to-sql-server-ssl-provider-error-0-the-mes